# How to convert back and forth between TextSize and FontSize with Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using `DisplayMetrics` and `FontMetrics` to compute a value for `TextSize` so that  the text inside the `Button` is not bigger that the button bounding box.

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
Display.GetMetrics(displayMetrics);
float scaledDensity = displayMetrics.ScaledDensity;

TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
paint.AntiAlias = true;
Paint.FontMetrics metrics = null;

Xamarin.Forms.Button button;
MyButtonRenderer renderer = ((MyButtonRenderer)Platform.GetRenderer(button));
Android.Widget.Button control = renderer.Control;

int maxFontSize = (int)renderer.defaultFontSize;
string text = button.Text;
Rect bounds = new Rect();

while (maxFontSize >= 0)
{
    paint.SetTypeface(control.Typeface);
    paint.TextSize = scaledDensity * maxFontSize;
    paint.GetTextBounds(text, 0, text.Length, bounds);
    metrics = paint.GetFontMetrics();
    if (bounds.Width() < control.MeasuredWidth && (metrics.Bottom - metrics.Top) < control.MeasuredHeight)
    {
        break;
    }
    maxFontSize--;
}
```

Then I thought that using `maxFontSize` to set the property `TextSize` for the button would make the text of the appropriate size:

```
renderer.Control.TextSize = maxFontSize * scaledDensity;
```

It doesn't work though, what I had to do was this instead:

```
float conversionScale = (float)renderer.Element.FontSize / renderer.Control.TextSize;
float maxTextSize = maxFontSize * scaledDensity;
renderer.Element.FontSize = maxTextSize * conversionScale;
```

Where `conversionScale` is what I use to covert `TextSize` to `FontSize`.

Is there a way to get this conversion factor from the API instead of inferring its value from the quotient of the two properties?

[Also asked at the official forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/115698/how-to-covert-textsize-to-fontsizes-from-xamarin-android-to-forms#latest).

Comment: [Just found this for you](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/)

Comment: @JoeLv thanks for the link, the docs related to fonts in Xamarin.Forms don't specify how to do that conversion though. Maybe I should take a look to the source code, good thing that Xamarin is FOSS :)